# update the textbox text property through loop

Tags: asp.net

I want to update the text property of my textbox control in Asp.Net from within loop.I have tried using Ajax updatepanel with the timer control but unable to update the text property.I have been searching this since last week but unable to find any answer any help would be higly appreciated

Following is the detail:

This is my button click event in this code you can see I am updating the

```
TxtContent.Text
```

within a loop the text is being returned by a user defined function called

```
ReturnBodyText()
```

afterwards I am assigning the text to the viewstate so that at the timer tick event I can recall the text and update the textbox text property and then at the timer tick event assigning the viewstate values to the textbox.

```
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList FilePath = (ArrayList)ViewState["ArrayList"];
    int i = 0;
    int b = 1;
    foreach(string[] sr in FilePath)
    {
        string Month = sr[i];
        string datewithzero;
        datewithzero = String.Format("{0:00}", b);
        string[] FilesArray = (string[])listfiles(Month, datewithzero).ToArray(typeof(string));

        foreach (string FileNameWithExtension in FilesArray)
        {
            ListBox4.Items.Add(FileNameWithExtension);
            TxtContent.Text = ReturnBodyText(Month, datewithzero, FileNameWithExtension);
            ViewState["Content"] = TxtContent.Text;
            Timer1.Enabled = true;
            Timer1_Tick(ViewState["Content"], e);
        }
        i = i + 1;
        b = b + 1;
    }
}

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TxtContent.Text =(string) ViewState["Content"];
    TxtContent.DataBind();
}
```

I Hope the above description will help you guys in understanding my problem

The complete aspx file and the code behind is as follows:

- **Aspx Code:**

  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

  <%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

  ```
      <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Height="509px" Width="59px">
      </asp:ListBox>

      <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Height="26px" onclick="Button2_Click" 
          Text="To be pressed first" Width="130px" />

      <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" onclick="Button3_Click" 
          Text="To be pressed 2nd" Width="131px" Height="26px" />

      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
      </asp:ScriptManager>

              <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" 
          ontick="Timer1_Tick" Enabled="False">
              </asp:Timer>
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
          <ContentTemplate>
              <asp:TextBox ID="TxtContent" runat="server" Height="508px" AutoPostBack="True" 
                  TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
              <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Height="26px" onclick="Button4_Click" 
                  Text="To be pressed Third" Width="122px" />

          </ContentTemplate>
          <Triggers>
              <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
          </Triggers>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>

  </div>
  </form>
  ```

  **- Codebehind:**

  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.UI;
  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
  using System.Net;
  using System.IO;
  using System.Collections;

  public partial class _Default : ftp 
  {

  ```
  protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      string[] array = (string[])listfiles().ToArray(typeof(string));
      ViewState["FolderName"] = array;
      foreach (string FileName in array)
      {
          ListBox1.Items.Add(FileName);
      }
  }
  protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      string[] arraylistbox2 = (string[])ViewState["FolderName"];
      string[] arrays = new string[12];
      ArrayList ListPath = new ArrayList();
      int dateFolder;
      foreach (string  FileName in arraylistbox2)
      {
          dateFolder =  Convert.ToInt16(FileName);
          dateFolder = dateFolder - 1;
          ListPath.Add((string[])(listfiles(FileName).ToArray(typeof(string))));
      }
      ViewState["ArrayList"] = ListPath;
  }
  protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      ArrayList FilePath = (ArrayList)ViewState["ArrayList"];
      int i = 0;
      int b = 1;
      foreach(string[] sr in FilePath)
      {
          string Month = sr[i];
          string datewithzero;
          datewithzero = String.Format("{0:00}", b);
          string[] FilesArray = (string[])listfiles(Month, datewithzero).ToArray(typeof(string));

          foreach (string FileNameWithExtension in FilesArray)
          {

              TxtContent.Text = ReturnBodyText(Month, datewithzero, FileNameWithExtension);
              ViewState["Content"] = TxtContent.Text;
              Timer1.Enabled = true;
              Timer1_Tick(ViewState["Content"], e);
          }
          i = i + 1;
          b = b + 1;
      }
  }
  protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

      TxtContent.Text =(string) ViewState["Content"];
      TxtContent.DataBind();


  }
  ```

Comment: Can you confirm your Timer is working? As in when you debug you are hitting the Timer1_Tick event?

Comment: If it is OK, can you post all code that is relevant? including .aspx content. That would let us reproduce your problem. Though I respect people who can solve this without that, I am not one of them.

Comment: @Bobby yes my Timer1_Tick event is working the debug mode hits breakpoint

Comment: are you getting an empty textbox in after the execution or the wrong value? I tried your code; and worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I am getting empty text box during the execution of the loop but it shows the value at the end when loop is finished the last value of the loop is being displayed in the text box where as I want the values the values during the loop as well

Comment: @mustafabattal Kindly check the aspx code and the code behind

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, your code did not help me much. However, I wrote this which I believe does what you want -partially-. It seems to me nothing more can be done though. Here is the code:

.aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="Timer1" Interval="1000" Enabled="true" 
            ontick="Timer1_Tick" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

aspx.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Threading;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected static string keeper;
        protected static bool inUse = false;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread worker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(workerFunction));
            worker.Start();
            return;
        }
        protected void workerFunction()
        {
            inUse = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                TextBox1.Text += "foo";
                keeper = TextBox1.Text;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            inUse = false;
            keeper = "";
        }
        protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (inUse)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(keeper);
            }
        }
    }
}
```