# How to reload the page control several times on one button click event in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Here I given the code which i want to do.

```
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
```

and my .cs file is having code like this

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
           Label1.Text = "Processing...updating label data:'" + i + "'";
           UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(Label1);
           UpdatePanel1.Update();

           Thread.Sleep(1000);
       }
  }
```

So from this only i want to see the label value update to UI for each time when for loop changes the label value.

Comment: You could use an ASP.NET Ajax [`Timer`-control](https://ajax.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/tutorials/IntroToTimerControl.aspx) instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583227/updating-asp-net-updatepanel-during-processing-loop

Comment: Thank You nikki.Thank You soo much....I searched a lot for this but your link is best.